# Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? Php script reset password

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I got almost everything to work, below you can find the steps that I go through and that already work.

Step1) send an email (with created token) to the email of the user that wants to reset there password

Step2) The user clicks on the provided token link and gets redirected to the reset password form

The problem

Step3) To reset their password they need to fill in the new password and press the reset button. What happens is that everything goes as planned but the database is not updated? I checked if it had something to do with the password hash and salt, but I don't now if that has something to do with it?
When registering with my script it creates a 64 byte hex password and 8 byte hex  salt.
Now when I use the same code, in the reset password script, it creates a password hash of 255 byte hex and also a larger salt then the register form.

Below you can find the code:

------------- DATABASE -------------

```
`password` char(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

`salt` char(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

------------- PHP Reset password -------------

```
require("connect.php");
```

$key = trim($_GET['key']);

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT resetToken, resetComplete FROM members WHERE resetToken = :token');
$stmt->execute(array(':token' => $key));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//if no token from db then kill the page
if(empty($row['resetToken'])){
    echo 'Invalid token provided, please use the link provided in the reset email.';
} elseif($row['resetComplete'] == 'Yes') {
    echo 'Your password has already been changed!';
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) { 
        echo "Please enter a password!";
        exit();
    } 

    if (empty($_POST['retype'])) { 
        echo "Please retype password!";
        exit();
    } 

    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['retype']) { 
        echo "Password doesn't match!";
        exit();
    } 

    $query = "UPDATE members SET password = :password, salt = :salt, resetComplete = 'Yes'  WHERE resetToken = :token";
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for ($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    }

    $query_params = array(  
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':token' => $row['resetToken']
    ); 

    try { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        die("Failed to run query");
    }

    echo "Change password success";
}
```

Comment: make sure your form isn't failing you, including its elements. Error reporting will tell you that, something you didn't include in your question. Make sure you are indeed using PDO to connect with.

Comment: where is this being populated from? `$row['resetToken']` - check for errors. Unclear question.

Comment: Do as they already told you, report your errors and also during this fixing print the actual exception, that may have all the information you need.

Comment: If you're not going to interact here, then I for one can't help you. I am moving on, good luck. We also are not your personal valets and "waiting for you" to shed some light on comments already given.

Comment: My apologies,I'm pretty new at php and was looking through the stuff you mentioned for the resetToken. I added the code were the token gets populated from and now I always get the invalid token error :s